# Unable to expand objects in Chrome debugger

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, debugging

I have a very simple object:

```
var myObject = {
    one: 1,
    two: 2,
};
debugger;
```

When the Chrome Javascript debugger is stopped at the debugger statement, I am unable to inspect the innards of myObject.

[image: View in debugger]

Clicking the disclosure triangle next to 'myObject' does nothing at all.

I can, however, type "myObject" in to the console and click the disclosure there.  But then I can only open variables nested one level deep.

I have the same problem whether stopped within JS in a web page, or served from node-inspector as part of the node.js (0.12.2) package.  Chrome v41.0.2272.118 (64-bit)

What am I missing?

Comment: Sometimes when the Chrome debugger freaks out it is a memory issue. I know I have had issues with inspecting things and had to close and reopen the browser for it to work.

Comment: What if you try stepping over to the next statement, and then inspecting?

Comment: Chrome can get in some really dumb states with the dev tools open. I agree with epascarello on this one. Restart Chrome.

Comment: Unfortunately this has been happening for months... chrome and the machine have been restarted many times.  I've tried stepping, stopping at later breakpoints to no avail... including margin-arrow breakpoints, not just 'debugger' statements.  This problem just started for me a few months ago.